# How does this sink faucet handle come off? (no visible screws)

Tags: plumbing-fixture

I've tried pulling up (to the point where I was afraid something would break) and am not getting any movement.  There are no holes or screws.  I considered prying but I'm afraid I'll damage the chrome ring underneath.  It is one solid piece except for that ring at the very bottom, which does not move.  Any alternative ideas?  Could applying heat hurt?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

unscrew the base part like a bottle cap

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I gave it my best effort by hand. Might try a strap wrench in a bit.

Comment: Good plan with strap wrench

Answer (score 1):

Heat would melt any rubber seals, so that's probably not a good idea.

Look at it from below the sink, there's probably a bolt head or some kind of fastener to hold it in place. If you unscrew that then you can pull the whole thing out.